# How can I create a navbar where each link is a piano key that appears to be pressed down when hovered?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to conceptualize a navbar for a musician's website which consists of piano keys (I would design keys in Aftereffects), and each link corresponds to a key which gets depressed upon hover.  I understand how to replace the content of one image with another in css, but this seems like it would be more complicated since the keys should appear cohesive--as though they form part of a piano.  I know this is hard to explain and I hope I'm being clear.  Is there a way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Maybe consider building it out entirely with CSS styling, and/or look into using canvas. There’s a lot you could do with either to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you CoderLee, I haven't heard of Canvas but I will check it out.

Comment: you’re welcome! I hope it helps lead you to your solution